# Traverse nested Dict in Julia-lang

Tags: dictionary, traversal, julia

While I traverse a nested Dict in Julia, it gives this Error:

```
ERROR: access to undefined reference
 in next at dict.jl:567
```

Here is the code where you can reproduce this error:

```
a = [0,19620,7291,32633,9,32513,42455,10045,31964,42455,11767,54]
b = [14318,16405,19,18913,19,8141,18958,12336,7,16588,17358,30]
d = Dict()
for aa in a
   for bb in b
     if ! haskey(d,aa)
        d[aa]=Dict()
     end
     d[aa][bb] = 0.5
   end
end 
for k1 in keys(d)
   s =0.0               
   for k2 in keys(d[k1])
     s+= d[k1][k2]
   end
   for k2 in keys(d[k1])
     d[k1][k2] = d[k1][k2] / s
   end
end
```

It's wired, if a = [0,1] b = [0,1], it works fine.

----Update-----

Actually, as long as array b has 11 distinct elements, the error would happen.
Also, if

```
d[k1][k2] = d[k1][k2] / s
```

become

```
d[k1][k2] = d[k1][k2] * s
```

or any other operations, the error disappear.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has now been fixed in the development branch, and will be available in the prerelease editions as soon as they gets updated.

See: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/5894/files

Answer (score 2):

The error probably comes from the fact that you modify the contents of `d[k1]` while you are iterating through it so the key iterator fails after you've modified the contents. (Why it only happens with some operations, I can't say.)

Anyhow, it can be fixed by changing the problematic loop to

```
for k2 in collect(keys(d[k1]))
    d[k1][k2] = d[k1][k2] / s
end
```

(I'm not sure that this is the best way to do it.)

Comment: Also,if array b has just 10 elements, there is no error. In this case, I still changed the value while iteration. However, I just change the value, not the structure of the dict, so iterator should not have problems.