# What happens when we run a julia-lang script?

Tags: bytecode, jit, julia

In my understanding, julia is a script language with a JIT compiler. But in java, you can find `*.class` files; In python, you can find `*.pyc` files. This means java and python need first convert its language to bytecode, then using VM to run this bytecode. However, I can not find the bytecode files for julia like `*.jlc`. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think a JIT neccessarily creates intermediate binaries? NodeJS = V8 also does not produce such files

Comment: Because I only know python and java, which both have bytecode. So why python and java have bytecode and julia chooses not to have the bytecode?

Comment: Bytecode is just a way to avoid having to re-compile a file over and over. While I think it would technically be possible to save LLVM bitcode, I dont think (=my opinion, not a definitive answer) that there is another reason beyond *nobody has taken time to do it yet*

Comment: That's reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: Source code (V8, Dart, Julia, etc.) and bytecode (JVM, .NET, Erlang, etc.) based VMs have different trade-offs. I'm not sure if having a bytecode based VM is a goal for Julia.

Comment: @EarthWorm I did a bit more research and compiled it into a full answer below.

Comment: @UliKöhler would you mind to look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926255/traverse-nested-dict-in-julia-lang/21928105?noredirect=1#21928105

Comment: @EarthWorm I tried but unfortunately my Julia language knowledge is way behind the knowledge needed to answer this :-( I hope the other answers will help you resolve your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is functionality to dump the LLVM bitcode in Julia:

See [`jl_dump_bitcode`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/20fb71780abf243e0f1064ee34edb45fea45c23f/src/codegen.cpp#L284).

Thanks to Isiah for pointing out that it is possible to use [`code_llvm`](http://blog.leahhanson.us/julia-introspects.html) to read the bitcode in the interpreter.

Note that in [`julia_trampoline`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/2fdefe2e3c37eb0fda47a5571ef166ad5e7dc6fe/src/init.c#L871) this function is used, depending on a `build_path` option. However this does not seem like an end-user interface to me.

In contrast to other JIT-based software like NodeJS (V8), it is however technically possible to dump the LLVM bitcode.

Comment: see `code_llvm` in the manual to do this from the REPL. there is functionality to read bitcode within LLVM itself, though we aren't using it. for static caching of the system image, julia compiles to LLVM bitcode and then uses llc to create a shared library which is linked against.

Comment: @Isaiah Thank you very much for noting this, I added it to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the manual: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/devdocs/eval/

Leah Hanson has written an excellent article [here](http://blog.leahhanson.us/post/julia/julia-introspects.html) on the 5 steps Julia performs to get from Julia code to native Assembly code: